# Algorithm for finding optimal use of products

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to solve a problem in Javascript allowing for optimal use of area with flooring products. I'll be either implementing this or looking for the algorithm in Javascript. The following is the problem:

Consider that I sell rolled carpets with width dimensions of 12, 13 and 15 ft. The length can be any size (because it's rolled).

Let's say I have 3 rooms:

- 25 x 10 (hallway)
- 30 x 30 (large room)
- 5 x 5 (closet)

How can I determine the minimal amount of product to use based on the available size options? I'd also like to ensure any wasted cuts are re-used. For larger rooms it's fine that there are seams to connect the rolled pieces. For example: in the hallway I can use a 15ft wide product and I'll have a roll remaining of 10 feet. I can use that to fill the closet.

The goal is to find the most optimal fit of product accounting for waste re-use.

Comment: If the carpet can be cut in any way, can't you just take the required area from the roll and cut it any way you like? this would mean zero waste.

Comment: @fafl - I think You buy it by the foot and whatever is left over is what is called `waste`

Comment: @shapiro: the point is that if any number of seams are acceptable, you can buy exactly the right amount no matter what widths you choose.

Comment: @ScottSauyet this is true. I suppose the tree off between seams and waste need to be defined differently for this to be an interesting question...

Comment: Thanks for weighing in everyone. The goal would be that the least amount of seams are cut to reduce overlap and make the floor more consistent. The rooms will likely always be off-sized from the width. So there will likely be "waste" that can be utilised in another room, requiring not buying additional length. In essence the optimal way to plan the cuts is the goal.

Comment: @ddibiase, since the problem boils down to seams vs waste, you're going to have to set a max amount of seam feet per sqft, or a max amount of waste in percent. Otherwise the problem is not solvable by algorithm, but only by intuition and preference. Also, you'll need to specify a minimum size for the room. Otherwise, waste could be infinite for an infinitely small room.

Comment: Ah I see, in that case lets say a minimum room size is 5x5. Maximum seams per sqft doesn't mean much to me. At a loss for how to determine that. Perhaps just pick a reasonable number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a large room of Width, and starting with our largest roll:

The integer, k15, of Width / 15ft gives the number of 15ft wide lengths.

Get Remaining Width = Width - 15ft x k15.

The integer, k13, of Remaining Width / 13ft gives the number of 13ft wide lengths.

Get next Remaining Width" = Remaining Width - 13ft x k13.

The integer, k12, of Remaining Width" / 12ft gives the number of 12ft wide  lengths.

Assuming that you will never have a room that is an integer of any combination of these three sizes, you will always have offcuts.

I think, area optimization and polgon geometry are two extremly complex fields, but I hope I have gone part way into at least defining your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did assume that this would end up being a a complex problem but algorithmically should be solvable. I was thinking that something like the Simplex Algorithm might be useful here?

Answer (score 0):

For three carpet widths of 12ft, 13ft & 15ft:

Assuming three rooms, with carpet rolls infinitly long, the algorithm for
determining the most efficient use is:

Give each room a dimension of: x0" & x1" for room one, y0" & y1" for room two,
and z0" & z1" for room three.

Sort this list such that the smallest dimension of each room is written first,
and the room with the largest 'smaller' dimension is also written first.

If x1" > x0", write it: (x0", x1") => (x0', x1')
If y1" > y0", write it: (y0", y1") => (y0', y1')
If z1" > z0", write it: (z0", z1") => (z0', z1')

And:

If z0' > x0' > y0' then write => (x0, x1), (y0, y1) & (z0, z1)

Given this ordered set, begin with the largest room, X, with its smaller
dimension as x0, the greater as x1.

Get the second largest room, Y.

We now need to find how we can lay the carpet in room X, such that the OFFCUT
will fill room Y in ONE or more lengths.

We need to choose between our three widths, so that the 'offcut will be as wide
as room Y'.

If x0 is 30, and y0 is 10, then 12ft + 13ft + 15ft gives us 30ft with 10ft spare
to use in room Y.

The same carries to room Z.

Problem solved.

Comment: Text between a pair of three (3) backtick marks is considered as code.  You need to remove the backticks at the beginning and end of your post...

Comment: I was unable to post my answer because it contained 'code'. I added back ticks (note correct spelling) so that I could post my answer. Now you say that I should take them away ?